# Troubleshooting a round fluorescent bulb with 4 pins in a square formation?

Tags: troubleshooting, fluorescent-lamp

I purchased a new magnifying desk lamp.  It uses a round fluorescent bulb.  I plugged it in, turned it on, and it doesn't light up.  No buzzing, no lighting, nothing.  So, how do I go about testing it to determine if the bulb is bad, or if the fixture is bad?

I don't want to go buy another bulb.  I just want to test the existing bulb and fixture.

The connectors on the bulb are in a square formation.  Is there a way to test it with an ohm meter?  I've scoured the internet for an answer to this and seems like a bunch of folks just guessing at answers.  Does anybody here actually know the right answer here?  Please don't respond if you're guessing, just if you really know.

Can I test output voltage on the socket/fixture to see if it's working properly?  What should the voltage be across the 4 receptors?  How to I test them?

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest posting a picture of the lamp in question

Comment: Unless it's got a fancy high-frequency CCFL driver, I'd expect mains voltage to be across those terminals so be careful. Some of the most common failures of fluoros are breakage and worn out filament, but a breakage is pretty easy to spot and a worn filament usually shows up as an orange glow at the ends that *won't* go away (a brief orange glow is normal) or a pinkish colour and not much white light. Nothing at all means that there might be something wrong elsewhere in the circuit other than the lamp (not that there's much in the average fluoro but anyway). Failing that, ask for a refund.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes there's two buttons: hit the ON button for a few seconds, and
watch the ends of the lamp (you may see a glow from the heaters).
If that doesn't start the lamp, there may be an automatic starter
(look for a small aluminum can, these are essentially thermal delay
switches that mimic the manual press-and-wait procedure).   The
starter will be bayonet-mounted, press/rotate and it should pop out.
Remove and reinstall it (checking that it isn't loose).

The lamp presumably has two filaments which heat to start the light,
and those will have some electrical conductivity - you can check them
with an ohmmeter (should read just a few ohms).  There's a gas-filled
envelope.  That, you can check with a Tesla coil, if you have one, or by
popping the tube into a microwave oven with a jar of water.   It'll
light up in seconds if it hasn't leaked.